# How add double quote and comma in a string after each break line Oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Im working in a pl sql block to iterate a string line and I need add to each line double quotes and  a comma similar of this:

[image]

My block is this:

```
DECLARE
v_fulltext varchar2(4000):= '                                                          Total   Total   Total Unbalanced Unbalanced       Flex    Nonflex
Journal Entry Source Name    Group ID           Status    Lines Batches Headers    Batches    Headers     Errors     Errors
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Manual                                    90005 Error        10       1       1          3          1          0          0
---------------------------- ------------------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       *** TOTALS ***                                         1       1       1          1          1          0          0';
v_full_text_2 varchar2(4000);
v_full_text_quote varchar2(4000);
counter number := 0;
BEGIN
FOR sumaryline IN(SELECT
            regexp_substr(v_fulltext, '[^('
                                || CHR(13)
                                || CHR(10)
                                || ')]+', 1, level) sumaryline
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        regexp_substr(v_fulltext, '[^('
                                || CHR(13)
                                || CHR(10)
                                || ')]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL)
LOOP
counter := counter +1;
v_full_text_quote := v_full_text_quote||'"'||sumaryline.sumaryline||'"'||chr(10);
  
END LOOP;
 dbms_output.put_line(v_full_text_quote);
END;
```

The output of this block is:
[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to add the comma after the double quote at the end of each line, I've tried adding:

```
v_full_text_2 := LTRIM (v_full_text_2 || ',' || v_full_text_quote, ',');
```

But this doesn't work.
Kind Regards.
Cesar.

Comment: You have successfully added double quotes, but comma is an issue for some reason. If you check your code, you do not add a comma anywhere where you add a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it here?

```
v_full_text_quote := v_full_text_quote||'"'||sumaryline.sumaryline||'",'||chr(10);
                                                                      ^
                                                                      |
                                                                     here
```

At the end, you'd just have to remove the final comma (as you don't need it):

```
END LOOP;
v_full_text_quote := rtrim(v_full_text_quote, ',');
```

Comment: The function:
v full_text quote := rtrim(v_ full_text quote, ',');
Don't remove the last comma

Comment: It should, if the very last character really is a comma.